# Git Bash: Windows 10 text is blurry and hard to read

Tags: git, git-bash

[image]I just set up a Windows 10 box, and the Git Bash terminal is giving me trouble. The output of a `git` command, like my uncommitted files in red, is blurry (fuzzy) and very hard to read. I found another post with recommend RGB colors that helped (the red is brighter at least), but the text is still not right. I guess it's the DPI that's too low?

Can someone give me recommendations to fix this? I didn't have this problem on my Windows 7 box.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot, if possible.

Comment: I've updated with a screenshot.

Comment: Hey have you tried going to go to the Adjust ClearType text in control panel?
Just type clear type text in the search bar windows thing (in bottom left corner)
see if its turned on. if it is just click next and see if you can tweek anything :)

Comment: Looks completely normal to me. Unfortunately, red on black is very hard on the eye. Are you sure you’re using the native display resolution etc?

Comment: @DanielB No, I'm not sure. How can I verify that?

Comment: @ScottChambers Thanks, trying that now.